# onitemclick listener doesnt work from Dialog

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm invoking an android Dialog from button click defined inside oncreate. The dialog appears with the set recyclerview. But clicking on recyclerview items doesnt work atall. Actually .setonclicklistener is defined. Pls find the code below.

```
public void openreview() {
    rv_review=(RecyclerView)slctssn.findViewById(R.id.rv_test);
    adapter_review = new review_adapter(this, questions);
    rv_review.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,10));
    rv_review.setAdapter(adapter_review);
    
    adapter_review.setOnItemClickListener(onClickedReview);

    
    slctssn.show();

}
```

Code for clicklistener definition :

```
public View.OnClickListener onClickedReview = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        int revposition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        mcqoptions one = new mcqoptions();
        mcqoptions two = new mcqoptions();
        mcqoptions three = new mcqoptions();
        mcqoptions four = new mcqoptions();

        one.setOption(qSet[revposition][1].toString());
        two.setOption(qSet[revposition][2].toString());
        three.setOption(qSet[revposition][3].toString());
        four.setOption(qSet[revposition][4].toString());


        nowStory.clear();
        nowStory.add(one);
        nowStory.add(two);
        nowStory.add(three);
        nowStory.add(four);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        questionTxt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtvQ);
        questionTxt.setText(qSet[qsetCntr][0].toString());

    }
};
```

Pls help to fix this.

here is my adapter code :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class review_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<review_adapter.rvViewHolder>{

    private List<review_objects> questions;
    private Context contxt;

    /*** for item click listener purpose as collected from GIT HUB  RohitSurwase /
     RvClickListenerExample ***/
    private View.OnClickListener adOnItemClickListener;

    public review_adapter(Context c, List<review_objects> review_objects){
        this.contxt= c;
        this.questions=review_objects;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public rvViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contxt);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reviews_layout,parent,false);
        return new rvViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull rvViewHolder holder, int position){
        String postmtr= questions.get(position).getSerial();

        holder.qstnum.setText(postmtr);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        
        return questions.size();
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(View.OnClickListener itemClickListener) {
        adOnItemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public class rvViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView qstnum;


        public rvViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            qstnum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.reviewqnum);

            itemView.setTag(this);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(adOnItemClickListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your adapter code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it. There were two problems.

1. questionTxt.setText(qSet[qsetCntr][0].toString()); it was to be like :
   `questionTxt.setText(qSet[revposition][0].toString());`

also one textview element in two places were sharing name. I corrected that also.

So the problem is over.

Thank you.

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. Please don't forget to mark your answer as accepted.